# Get values on 1 line based on unique identifier

Tags: sql

I'm trying to write a query to get the values of a table placed onto a single line based on a specific key.

```
  table.ID    | table.ACCOUNT |
==================================
 12345        | 456789        |
 12345        | ABCDEF        |
 12345        | HIJKLM        |
```

For example, I want to get all the ACCOUNTs for ID 12345 (above) onto one line so it looks like what is below.

```
  table.ID    | table.ACCOUNT1 | table.ACCOUNT2 | table.ACCOUNT3 |
====================================================================
 12345        | 456789         | ABCDEF         | HIJKLM         |
```

I think I want to join the table to itself but I keep getting the same values in the 2nd and 3rd ACCOUNT fields (i.e. 456789 shows up in all 3).

Comment: which RDBMS you are using?

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio, nope it's not. OP wants to list all of the accounts group by id. based on RDBMS there are different ways like the answer posted and `group_concat()` in MySQL and XML processing in SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

If you don't really need separate columns for all of the accounts, consider using an aggregate function such as [`string_agg`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-aggregate.html) in Postgres:

```
SELECT id, string_agg(account, ',') FROM table GROUP BY id
```

This will produce a result with two columns, the id and a string containing all of the accounts for the id separated by `,` characters.

Answer (score 0):

If you know there are at most three accounts per id, you can pivot the data.  In most databases, you can use `row_number()` and conditional aggregation:

```
select id,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then account end) as account_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then account end) as account_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then account end) as account_3
from (select t.*
             row_number() over (partition by id order by id) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by id;
```

Unlike a string aggregation method, this puts the values into separate columns.